# SegFault on Make xmlrpc-c

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

Im trying to instal xmlrpc-c but I have this problem (configure work well)

> make -C include/ -f /home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c//include/Makefile \
>         all  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c/include' make[1]: Nothing to be done for`
>   all'. make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c/include'
>   make -C lib/ -f /home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c//lib/Makefile \
>         all  make[1]: Entering directory`/home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c/lib' make -C util/ -f /home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c/lib/util/Makefile \
>         all  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c/lib/util' gcc -c -DNDEBUG -Wall -W
>   -Wno-uninitialized -Wundef -Wimplicit -Winline -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-common -g -O3   -Isrcdir/lib/util/include -I/home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c   cmdline_parser.c cmdline_parser.c: In function ‘cmd_processOptions’: cmdline_parser.c:297:1: internal
>   compiler error: Segmentation fault Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate. See
>   <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
>   Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/cc1uevda.out file, please attach
>   this to your bugreport. make[2]: *** [cmdline_parser.o] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/sampa/tmp/xmlrpc-c/lib/util'
>   make[1]: *** [util/all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/sampa/tmp/xml rpc-c/lib' make: *** [lib/all] Error 2

Any idea?

Comment: Since this is solved without detailed information about what fixed it, and it appears no more help is needed, this may be closed as *too localized*.

Answer (score -1):

Solved after upgrade Ubuntu to 12.04